# DispatchQueue.main.async causes the search to hang. Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableView, each cell is loaded with an image from the internet via DispatchQueue.main.async.

I implemented a search on an array, the data from which is output to a table. Because of DDispatchQueue.main.async, the emulator starts to hang a lot, but if you remove it, everything works fine, how do I implement loading images without causing a load?

Image upload code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
       if let url = URL(string: "https://storage.googleapis.com/iex/api/logos/\(stock.displaySymbol).png") {
           if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                self.stockLogoImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                self.imageLoadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
           } 
       }
}
```

Search extension code:

```
extension StocksViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        searchStocks(searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
    
    func searchStocks(_ searchText: String) {
        searchStocksList = stocks.filter({(stock: Stock) -> Bool in
            return stock.displaySymbol.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) || stock.description.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        })
        
        stocksTableView.reloadData()
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `Data(contentsOf:)`. Read and heed [the warning](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1413892-init) It is probably easiest to use SDWebImage or Kingfisher.  If you don't want to use an external framework then you should use `URLSession` to fetch the content from the network

Answer (score 0):

Don't do networking on the main queue, It's the UIKit work that must be done on the main queue.

```
   // Network on background queue
   if let url = URL(string: ....),
      let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
        let img = UIImage(data: data)

        // Dispatch back to main to update UI
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.stockLogoImageView.image = img
           self.imageLoadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
       }
   }
```